# PHONEGAP how can i build my application including the database

Tags: android, cordova

hi i am new to phonegap .. i try using phonegap with database now, i am able to display the records in emulator / fetch record .. but when i try to build the application in build.phonegap.com to make .apk when i install the application and run in my android no record display .. my question is how can i build my application including the database ? i have .db already where should i place it or something do i need to add some script ? hope u get my point and sorry for my english..

here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    }


    function clickFunc(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(selectData);
    }


    function selectData(tx){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test",[],resultSuccess,resultError);
    }

    function resultError(error){
        alert("Error: "+error);
    }

    function resultSuccess(tx, response){
        var div = document.getElementById('display');
        var tmp = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>DATA</th></tr>";
        for(var i = 0;i<response.rows.length;i++){
            tmp += "<tr><td>" + response.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).data + "</td></tr>";
            div.innerHTML = tmp;
        }
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<input type="button" value="FITCH" id="btnSelect" onclick="clickFunc();"/>
<div id="display">

</div>
```

Comment: did you use which data base like sqllite or indexdb or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Your create only database but your not create any table and nothing to insert it. So that your apk doesn't produce your excepted result.

So you will try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Storage Example</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.4.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">


    // Wait for Cordova to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // Cordova is ready
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
    }

    function populateDB(tx) {
         tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DEMO');
         tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DEMO (id unique, data)');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
         tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO DEMO (id, data) VALUES (2, "Second row")');
    }


    function clickFunc(){
        var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Cordova Demo", 200000);
        db.transaction(selectData);
    }


    function selectData(tx){
        tx.executeSql("SELECT * FROM test",[],resultSuccess,resultError);
    }

    function resultError(error){
        alert("Error: "+error);
    }

    function resultSuccess(tx, response){
        var div = document.getElementById('display');
        var tmp = "<table><tr><th>ID</th><th>DATA</th></tr>";
        for(var i = 0;i<response.rows.length;i++){
            tmp += "<tr><td>" + response.rows.item(i).id + "</td><td>" + response.rows.item(i).data + "</td></tr>";
            div.innerHTML = tmp;
        }
    }


    </script>
  </head>
  <body>

<input type="button" value="FITCH" id="btnSelect" onclick="clickFunc();"/>
<div id="display">

</div>
```

If you need more details please refer this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage